# Date from textbox to datetimepicker

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

I have a form with `DateTimePicker` and `TextBox`
and want the `DateTimePicker` to get its value from `TextBox`

i tried

> DateTimePicker.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox.Text);

but it didn't work
any help please ?

thanks

Comment: You'll need some JavaScript to bind `DateTimePicker` to your input field.  Have you looked at examples https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/?  Once you look and try it out, let us know if you have any follow up questions.

Comment: i'm using c# winform
let me ask another way .. i want the datetimepicker value matches the date in textbox when update it

Comment: Is it Bootstrap DateTimePicker?

Comment: Posted code works.  Probably better to use a DateTime.TryParse function to avoid exceptions from wonky data.  Where are you calling this code?  Make sure the code is running by using a debug break stop on that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do it is to call TryParse of DateTime on the content of the TextBox and set the DateTimePicker with that DateTime.

```
DateTime dateTimeParsed;
if (DateTime.TryParse(textBox.Text, out dateTimeParsed))
    dateTimePicker.Value = dateTimeParsed;
else
{
    // Handle formatting errors
}
```